# How to remote access MySql Workbench using vb.net 2008 on windows platform

Tags: vb.net, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a desktop application with VB.NET (Windows Forms), 
Problem :

I want to create a client-server application, it means I just need 1 database on the server.

I have a computer and a laptop. I set my laptop's IP to 192.168.1.1 and my computer's IP to 192.168.1.2.

Now I place the database on my computer, the database name is dbname.

Problem is, how to connect my computer's database from my laptop?

Specification :

I'm using this string below for my connection :

connectionString="server=192.168.0.1;Port=3306;User Id=root ;Password=pass;database=dbname;"

I have already disable the firewall. Ping are working... 
But it gives error Database not found

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to the mysql server to do data access?  I am not quite sure what you mean by "remote access MySql Workbench using vb.net".

If you need to do data access to mysql from vb.net (or any other .net language) , you'll need to use the msql connector for .net:  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: I have already set the connetor... It works on localhost on same system.. but it didn't work from other PC..

Comment: Are you using the correct server IP address (you have  `192.128.0.1` in your connection string)?  If you are connecting to mysql on the computer from the laptop you need to use `192.168.1.2`, which is what you said the computer's IP address was.

Comment: If you also have a firewall running on your laptop you may also need to make sure your computer is allowing incoming traffic on port `3306`, preferably only from your private network.